# Remove ï»¿ from string with regular expressions

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace, special-characters

I am trying to remove the following characters `ï»¿` from a string. However only `»¿`is being removed.

```
Code:

protected function removeSpecialChars($comment)
{
    //Remove 'ï»¿'
    return preg_replace('/[ï»¿]+/', '', $comment);
}

Input:

Your spellingï»¿ is amazing

Output:

Your spellingï is amazing
```

Any help would be much appreciated - this is driving me mad.

**UPDATE**

Thank you for all the comments. I am getting the string from a JSON url - specifically `GData` from Google. I tested the code with a normal string and it works fine, but when testing it on the JSON it does not work.

Code to get comments from JSON URL:

```
$url = 'https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/' . $video_id .'/comments?alt=json&max-results=50&v=2';
$comments = array();

$json   = file_get_contents($url);
$data   = json_decode($json, TRUE);

foreach($data["feed"]["entry"] as $item)
{
    array_push($comments, $item["content"]['$t']);
}
```

Not sure if it do with the character encoding of the JSON...

Comment: Can you be more specific on your PHP, web server and OS versions? For me, its working fine!

Comment: Check execution here: http://codepad.org/myrBukT8

Comment: Which character encoding do you use?

Comment: It's worth pointing out that the character sequence `ï»¿` is what is displayed if you have a UTF-8 BOM (byte order mark) character at the start of a file, but the file isn't being recognised as UTF-8. The best way to solve this is to save your files as UTF-8 but without the BOM, or use the right encoding when you open the file so that the BOM is recognised for what it is. If this is because of a BOM, you shouldn't need to be removing it with regex; if you are, then you're doing something wrong further up the line.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add the u modifier:

```
return preg_replace('/[ï»¿]+/u', '', $comment);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
return preg_replace("/\\357\\273\\277/um", '', $comment);
```